# Git commands on modified files in order shown

Tags: git

Lets say I do a git status and get

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1
    modified:   file2
    modified:   file3

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Up until now when choosing the files to commit I have typed (or middle mouse button clicked)

```
git add file2
git add file3
```

Is there a shorter way to add by order shown? Like

```
git add 2,3
```

to add `file2` and `file3`? This also applies to `git reset`, `git diff` etc.

I understand in this simple case I could

```
git add .
git reset file1
```

to achieve the same effect, but I am enquiring for more than just a few modified files with extremely long path names;

```
modified:   very/very/long/path/to/file1
modified:   an/even/longer/path/to/file2
modified:   a/much/much/longer/path/to/file3
modified:   path/to/file4    
modified:   different/path/to/file5
```

Comment: Try using `git add -i`, then specify option 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git add` works with pattern too, so you can do `git add file[23]` to add only those 2 files, its up to you after to define which patterns to use

on mac os, on my repo, here are the series of step which work

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ touch file1 file2 file3
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  file1
  file2
  file3

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git add file[23]
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

  new file:   file2
  new file:   file3

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  file1

fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   6 fhenri  staff  204 10 sep 12:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 fhenri  staff  340 10 sep 12:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 fhenri  staff  340 10 sep 12:48 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    0 10 sep 12:48 file1
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    0 10 sep 12:48 file2
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    0 10 sep 12:48 file3
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$
```

If you have directories and subdirectories, it can also work

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ ls -R
afolder file1 file2 file3 folder  yfolder

./afolder:
file1

./folder:
file2

./yfolder:
subfolder

./yfolder/subfolder:
file3
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git add \*file[23]
fhenri@machine:~/project/examples/gitadd$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

  new file:   file2
  new file:   file3
  new file:   folder/file2
  new file:   yfolder/subfolder/file3

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  afolder/
  file1
```

Comment: The comma would add a file called `file,` as well, the correct pattern would be `file[23]` (and also note that if you don't quote the pattern then it is expanded by the shell, not by Git).

Comment: hum, not sure about the bash, but on mac os file[2,3] works

Comment: Yes it works, but it means "add files that match `file2` or `file,` or `file3`" which is not what you want, you only want `file2` or `file3`. The group `[2,3]` does not mean "2 or 3" it means "2 or comma or 3"

Comment: And although it's true that Git does support patterns like that, in your example the shell expands the pattern and runs `git add file2 file3` and Git never sees the pattern. If you run `git add 'file[23]'` (with quotes) then the shell doesn't expand it, and Git sees  the pattern and expands it. In this case it doesn't make any difference, but sometimes it does. You can see the difference by running `echo file[23]` and comparing to `echo 'file[23]'`

Comment: ok, I do understand now but do we know the differences that git uses for pattern, or using the shell pattern is a better practice ? is it better to leave it to git to expand the pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git add file1 file2 file3
```

Remember to separate each file with a space.

Comment: If you use a tool called git-cola, you just need to select the files you want to commit, type the commit message and press the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is *possible*, e.g. using a shell script (or equivalent shell function):

```
#!/bin/sh
git status \
  | awk 'BEGIN { indices[0]=0; split("'"$1"'", indices, ",");  } $1=="modified:" { ++count ; for (i in indices) if (indices[i] == count) print $2 }' \
  | xargs echo git add
```

This will allow you to run `git add 1,2` to add the first and second modified files.

But it's probably better to find a different solution.

When I need to add files with long names I simply run `git status` and select each filename by double-clicking with the mouse and paste it into a `git add` command with the middle mouse button.

Another option is to run `git add -p` which will interactively add each change in each changed file:

```
$ git add -p
diff --git a/foo, b/foo,
index e69de29..8b13789 100644
--- a/foo,
+++ b/foo,
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

If you type `a` it will add all changes from the file and move on to the next file. If you type `d` it will not add any changes from the file and will move on to the next file. So you can just use `a` or `d` to add or skip each file.